# How to run a function at a specific time everyday using ios swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to execute a function every day at a specific time. I want to run this function when user active on the app. I have also tried timer for that but I am already using the timer for other function which is running in every 60 minutes.

So can anyone provide me solution how can I call function every day at a specific time(suppose 5 am).

Thanks

Comment: Do you really think this has never ever been asked before on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @matt I have already checked on Stackoverflow but does not get any solution.